# Validation of Hidden Multi-Checkbox/Input fields

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, validation, checkbox

In order to deal with validation of fields with multiple optional checkboxes I used webshims polyfill.

The form has checkboxes that hide/unhide sections of the form.

Initial task was to only validate/require the hidden sections if they became visible.

My initial idea was to use the features of webshims polyfill to only require a hidden field if the checkbox associated with making that field visible was checked.

Problem #1:
Some of the hidden sections include these multi-checkbox type fields that need validation. How do I get these fields to make use of webshims' data-grouprequired="" feature so I can validate these multi-checkbox fields?

Problem #2:
There is one hidden section (Registries/id=div3) with 5 input text fields - the end user only needs to fill in at least one of these fields. How do I make it so that when this hidden section becomes visible, only a minimum of one of the 5 fields is required in order to validate the form?

Alternatively, if there is a better solution I'd love to learn. I am very new to this.

Here's the relevant code from the form:

```
   <script>
     webshim.setOptions('forms', {
        lazyCustomMessages: true,
        addValidators: true
    });

    webshim.polyfill('forms forms-ext');
    </script>

    <script>
    function addTableRow() {
        var $tableRow = $('tr.model-row:first-child');
        var $clonedRow = $tableRow.clone().show();
        $('#stmember').append($clonedRow);
        }

    function myDeleteFunction() {
        var $memberTRs = $('tr', '#stmember');
        // If rowcount === 1, hide first row, don't remove it!!
        var rowCount = $memberTRs.length;
        if (rowCount === 1) {
            $('tr.model-row:first-child').hide();
            return;
        }
        $memberTRs.last().remove();
        }

        jQuery(function() {

        $('#delete').click(function() {
            myDeleteFunction();
        });

        $('#add').click(function() {
            addTableRow();
        });

    });
    </script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    function showMe (it, box) {
        var vis = (box.checked) ? "block" : "none";
        document.getElementById(it).style.display = vis;
    }
    </script>
<body>
<form method="post" action="mailto:you@example.com" enctype="text/plain">
    <div class="row 50%">
        <div class="12u">
        Which of the following would you like to do with your specified patient population? Check all that apply.<br />
            <ul class="list">
                <li><input type="checkbox" id="recruit" name="todo" value="1" data-grouprequired="" onclick="showMe('div1', this)"> Recruitment for research</li>
                <li><input type="checkbox" id="edc" name="todo" value="2" onclick="showMe('div2', this)"> Electronic Data Capture</li>
                <li><input type="checkbox" id="registry" name="todo" value="3" onclick="showMe('div3', this)"> Registry</li>
                <li><input type="checkbox" id="dextract" name="todo" value="4" onclick="showMe('div4', this)"> Data Extraction</li> 
                <li><input type="checkbox" id="ptpop" name="todo" value="5">Estimate of number of patients in target population</li>    
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
<div id="div1" style="display:none">
    <div class="row 50%">
        <div class="12u">
            <h3><strong>Recruitment</strong></h3>
            What methods would you like to use for patient recruitment? Check all that apply.<br />
                <ul class="list">
                    <li><input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike"> Patient Notification Through MyChart</li>
                    <li><input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Car"> Study Team Member Notification When Appropriate Patient Checks In</li>
                    <li><input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Car"> Provider Notification During Patient Encounter</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>  
    </div>      
    <div id="div2" style="display:none">
        <h3><strong>Electronic Data Capture</strong></h3>
        <div class="row 50%">
            <div class="6u 12u (mobile)">
            How would you like to capture data on your patient population? Check all that apply.<br />
            <ul class="list" style="margin-bottom: 0px; padding-bottom: 0px;">
                <li><input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike"> Patient entry through MyChart</li>
                <li><input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Car"> Patient entry through Welcome</li>
                <li><input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Car"> Patient entry through REDCap</li>
                <li><input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Car"> Clinician entry through EPIC</li>    
                <li><input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Car"> Clinician entry through REDCap</li>
                <li><input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Car"> MHi-GO (Mobile Application)</li> 
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="6u 12u(mobile)">
        Where would you like the data delivered to? (Server name, share name, or JHBox, Enterprise NAS, etc.)
            <input name="subname" type="text" data-dependent-validation='{"from": "edc", "prop": "required"}' />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row 50%">
        <div class="6u 12u(mobile)">
        In what format would you like to receive your data? (Excel, pipe-delimited, CSV, SQL tables)
            <input name="subjhed" type="text" data-dependent-validation='{"from": "edc", "prop": "required"}' />
        </div>
        <div class="6u 12u(mobile)">
        Would you like the data visualized and if so how? (Graphs, tables, diagrams, other)
            <input name="subemail" type="text" data-dependent-validation='{"from": "edc", "prop": "required"}' />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="div3" style="display:none">
    <div class="row 50%">
    <h3><strong>Registries</strong></h3>
    </div>
    <h3 class="quest-header"><strong>What information and/or metrics of your patient population would you like to track over time?</strong></h3>
    Please specify if applicable:
    <div class="row 50%">
            <div class="6u 12u(mobile)">
            Diagnoses:
                <input name="subjhed" type="text" />
            </div>
            <div class="6u 12u(mobile)">
            Problem List:
                <input name="subemail" type="text" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row 50%">
            <div class="6u 12u(mobile)">
            Medications:
                <input name="subjhed" type="text" />
            </div>
            <div class="6u 12u(mobile)">
            Labs:
                <input name="subemail" type="text" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row 50%">   
            <div class="6u 12u(mobile)">
            Other:
                <input name="subjhed" type="text" />
            </div>
        </div>  
    </div>
    <div id="div4" style="display:none">
        <div class="row 50%">
            <div class="12u">
            <h3><strong>Data Extraction</strong></h3>
            What data would you like to extract?
            <textarea name="description" data-dependent-validation='{"from": "dextract", "prop": "required"}' ></textarea>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row 50%">
            <div class="6u 12u(mobile)">
            Where would you like the data delivered to? (Server name, share name, or JHBox, Enterprise NAS, etc.)
                <input name="subemail" type="text" data-dependent-validation='{"from": "dextract", "prop": "required"}' />
            </div>
            <div class="6u 12u(mobile)">
            In what format would you like to receive your data? (Excel, pipe-delimited, CSV, SQL tables)
                <input name="subjhed" type="text" data-dependent-validation='{"from": "dextract", "prop": "required"}' />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div
        <div class="row 50%">
            <div class="12u">
            <center>
                <ul class="actions">
                    <li><input type="submit" value="Submit Request" /></li>
                    <li><input type="submit" value="Save & Continue Later" /></li>
                    <li><input type="reset" value="Clear form" /></li>
                </ul>
            </center>
            </div>
       </div>
  </form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually figured this out myself. Disabled all hidden fields. Had them become  enabled on becoming visible. For the multiple text fields was able to use data-grouprequired from webshims  polyfill but had to create a custom error message.